# How to find all input element after certain labels and apply a function to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do this: on click of a button, put placeholder in all input fields marked with a red asterisk, the following code finds all asterisks:

```js
var asterisks = $("label > span:contains('*').red");
$("#submit").click(function () {
  console.log(asterisks);
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
    <span class="red">*</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename">
</div>
<div>
<label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
  <span class="red">*</span>
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

However, I tried to find the inputs below these asterisks and put the same placeholder in them, the following code does not work:

```js
var inputs = $("label > span:contains('*').red").next().find("input");

$("#submit").click(function () {
  console.log(inputs);
  inputs.attr("placeholder", "This is a placeholder");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
    <span class="red">*</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename">
</div>
<div>
<label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename">
</div>
<div>
<label for="Lastname">
  Last Name
  <span class="red">*</span>
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname">
</div>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just use HTML 5 validation? `<input type="text" id="Lastname" required>`

Comment: So you would need to select the parent and find the sibling

Comment: @epascarello I would like to use the red asterisks to find the mandatory input fields

Comment: `.next()` gives the next sibling, not the next input/next line of html or anything else.  Your `span.red`s do not have any further siblings.

Comment: @epascarello going for the red asteriks is probably the least performant way you could do it. There is a reason we have specific tags,  classes and id's. Why not add a `is-mandatory` class to those inputs for example?

Comment: @TheFool I agree, but the original code was written in MVC and I could not do much about the class etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var asterisks = $("label > span:contains('*').red");
$("#submit").click(function() {
  asterisks.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().attr("placeholder", "whut?");
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="Forename">
    Forename
    <span class="red">*</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="Middlename">
  Middle Names
  <span class="red">*</span>
</label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

You were very close to the solution. You found asterisks inside the labels so you need parent elements next sibling by chaining parent().next()

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("label > span:contains('*').red").next().find("input");
```

The `.find()` method looks at a matched element's child element. So you are getting the `.next()` element, and then looking for a child within it.

The `input` element is a sibling of the "red" element's parent. So you will need to do this:

```js
$("label > span:contains('*').red").parent().next();
```